# Lines from each vertex of a triangle to diagonal intersections of constructed squares on opposite sides concur. Does this point have a name or number?

Tags: euclidean-geometry

Given any triangle ABC. Join vertices A,B,C with midpoints (diagonal intersections) say P, Q, R of squares constructed on opposite sides BC, AC and AB respectively. The lines AP, BQ and CR concur at a point say H.

It can be proved that this point is the orthocenter of triangle PQR.

Does the point H have any name or number in the original triangle ABC?

Comment: You should include an illustration/diagram

Comment: Perhaps someone could help? I have had problems uploading images to math stackexchange.

Comment: Please link the image here in the comments section. I'll edit it into the question

Comment: It's Vecten Point (X(485) in [ETC](https://faculty.evansville.edu/ck6/encyclopedia/ETC.html)).

Comment: I am afraid I can't even make a link to the image here in the comments section. My image is a rather poor photo of a hand drawn construction, so it would be infinitely better if someone used to GeoGebra or some other geometric program tool could supply an image. By the way H is also the circumcenter of a different triangle made by constructing parallellograms on each of the neighbouring squares and joining the three points "opposite" the vertices. An article by D. Detemple and S. Harolds: " A round-up of square problems" has the details.

Comment: Shouldn't the comment above @intelligenti pauca be called an answer? It perfectly answers my question.